# How to append an element to an array column of a Spark Dataframe?

Tags: arrays, dataframe, scala, apache-spark, append

Suppose I have the following DataFrame:

```
scala> val df1 = Seq("a", "b").toDF("id").withColumn("nums", array(lit(1)))
df1: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: string, nums: array<int>]

scala> df1.show()
+---+----+
| id|nums|
+---+----+
|  a| [1]|
|  b| [1]|
+---+----+
```

And I want to add elements to the array in the `nums` column, so that I get something like the following:

```
+---+-------+
| id|nums   |
+---+-------+
|  a| [1,5] |
|  b| [1,5] |
+---+-------+
```

Is there a way to do this using the `.withColumn()` method of the DataFrame? E.g.

```scala
val df2 = df1.withColumn("nums", append(col("nums"), lit(5)))
```

I've looked through the API documentation for Spark, but can't find anything that would allow me to do this.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{lit, array, array_union}

val df1 = Seq("a", "b").toDF("id").withColumn("nums", array(lit(1)))
val df2 = df1.withColumn("nums", array_union($"nums", lit(Array(5))))
df2.show

+---+------+
| id|  nums|
+---+------+
|  a|[1, 5]|
|  b|[1, 5]|
+---+------+
```

The `array_union()` was added since spark 2.4.0 release on 11/2/2018, 7 months after you asked the question, :) see https://spark.apache.org/news/index.html

Answer (score 5):

You can do it using a `udf` function as

```
def addValue = udf((array: Seq[Int])=> array ++ Array(5))

df1.withColumn("nums", addValue(col("nums")))
  .show(false)
```

and you should get

```
+---+------+
|id |nums  |
+---+------+
|a  |[1, 5]|
|b  |[1, 5]|
+---+------+
```

*Updated*
Alternative way is to go with dataset way and use map as

```
df1.map(row => add(row.getAs[String]("id"), row.getAs[Seq[Int]]("nums")++Seq(5)))
  .show(false)
```

where add is a case class

```
case class add(id: String, nums: Seq[Int])
```

I hope the answer is helpful

Comment: is there a more efficient way for big arrays? Since by default, `Seq` is `List` and appending `List` is slow

Comment: Majarjan thanks but in terms of performance, it is the same. So it is not related to what I'm saying

Comment: Thanks for the upvote and letting me know that the performance are the same. you can try rdd way to check the performance. @MinhThai

Answer (score 3):

If you are, like me, searching how to do this in a Spark SQL statement; here's how:

```
%sql

select array_union(array("value 1"), array("value 2"))
```

You can use array_union to join up two arrays. To be able to use this, you have to turn your value-to-append into an array. Do this by using the array() function.

You can enter a value like array("a string") or array(yourColumn).

Answer (score 0):

Be careful with using spark array_join. It is removing duplicates. So you will not get expected results if you have duplicated entries in your array. And it is at least costing O(N). So when I use it with a array aggregate, it became an O(N^2) operation and took forever for some large arrays.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Agreed. How did you do it then? Did you use an UDF?

Comment: I ended up writing a UDF that is specific to my case without using array append.

Answer (score 0):

**Spark 3.4+** has a method to append an element to the end of the array:

```scala
array_append($"nums", 5)
```

**Spark 3.5+** has a method to append an element to the beginning of the array:

```scala
array_prepend($"nums", 5)
```

---

Example:

```scala
val df1 = Seq("a", "b").toDF("id").withColumn("nums", array(lit(1)))
df1.show()
// +---+----+
// | id|nums|
// +---+----+
// |  a| [1]|
// |  b| [1]|
// +---+----+

val df2 = df1.withColumn("nums", array_append($"nums", 5))
df2.show()
// +---+------+
// | id|  nums|
// +---+------+
// |  a|[1, 5]|
// |  b|[1, 5]|
// +---+------+

val df3 = df1.withColumn("nums", array_prepend($"nums", 5))
df3.show()
// +---+------+
// | id|  nums|
// +---+------+
// |  a|[5, 1]|
// |  b|[5, 1]|
// +---+------+
```