# How to add string to string array column in spark dataset

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-2.0

I have a "Dataset(Row)" as below

```
+-----+--------------+
|val  |  history     |
+-----+--------------+
|500  |[a=456, a=500]|
|800  |[a=456, a=500]|
|784  |[a=456, a=500]|
+-----+--------------+
```

Here val is "String" and history is an "string array". I'm trying to add the content in val column to the history column, so that my dataset looks like :

```
+-----+---------------------+
|val  |  history            |
+-----+---------------------+
|500  |[a=456, b=500, c=500]|
|800  |[a=456, b=500, c=800]|
|784  |[a=456, b=500, c=784]|
+-----+---------------------+
```

A similar question is discussed here https://stackoverflow.com/a/49685271/2316771 , but I don't know scala and couldn't create a similar java solution.

Please help me to achieve this in java

Comment: Are you sure that is a string *array*? Why does it have keys?

Comment: It is just a format for convenience. But it is a string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Spark 2.4 (not before), you can use the `concat` function to concat two arrays. In your case, you could do something like:

```java
df.withColumn("val2", concat(lit("c="), col("val")))
  .select(concat(col("history"), array(col("val2")));
```

NB: the first time I use `concat` is to concat strings, the second time, to concat arrays. `array(col("val2"))` creates an array of one element.

Answer (score 0):

I coded a solution but I'm not sure if it can be further optimized

```
    dataset.map(row -> {
        Seq<String> seq = row.getAs("history");
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>(JavaConversions.seqAsJavaList(seq));
        list.add("c="+row.getAs("val"));

        return RowFactory.create(row.getAs("val"),list.toArray(new String[0]));},schema);
```